# Execute R files through an R script

Tags: r

I'm not sure how to properly ask this but basically I have a very populated single 400 line file on a kaggle competition I was working on and I want to split it up into multiple files (say one file is for data cleaning, another file is for feature engineering etc) in such a way that I can have one main file that will go from reading the csv files all the way to making the model predictions, how can I do that in R? Do I have to encapsulate the entire files into one function each and then use that? If so how does that work? Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like your 400-line script is literal commands, one-by-one. Have you considered using a `function`al approach? Define functions to do certain steps. Whether you decide one-function-per-file or something else is up to you. Regardless, if you have a "master" script, then it should `source` the remaining scripts to either (a) load their functions so that the master script can use them, or (b) execute all of the not-function code within each file.

Comment: Yep that's what I want! I did not know the command existed, someone else also answered with this, thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `source` command and pass it the filename. try `?source`

Comment: well that was quick! that is exactly what I wanted thanks